# Evaluate this number. Is it close to 1 or 0?

Tags: probability, numerical-methods

$$x = \frac{n!\binom mn}{m^n}.$$

Now here's the hard part: What if $m = 52!$ and n is about $10^{14}?$

The number is a probability (the probability that no two deck of cards have been the same supposing there have been around $10^{14}$ shuffles in history if i am not mistaken)

Comment: For what it's worth if you just need a raw answer for a homework assignment on this matter, there might be a chance your instructor is fine with it left relatively unsimplified like that. Or you can just dump it into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Comment: i'm guessing we use stirling's approximation? Sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: You probably want to calculate $L = \log_{10} \frac{m!}{n! (m-n)! m^n}$ using [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for the factorials, then see whether $10^L$ is closer to $0$ or $1$, that is, whether $L$ is negative and large magnitude or negative and tiny magnitude.  As a check, actually computing $\log_{10}(52!)$ gives $67.906{\dots}$ without an approximation.

Comment: By unfolding $\binom mn$ to $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!n!}$ one easily sees that your $x\le\frac1{n!}$. This inequality squeezes it closer to $0$ the larger $n$ is, so your interpretation of the fraction doesn't look likely.

Comment: What you're really after is an approximation to the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) probability. Here it is relevant that $\sqrt{52!}\ggg 10^{14}$.

Comment: @Troposphere:  I saw your comments after posting my answer, though I was a few minutes behind them.  They have the meat of it.  If you would like to post an answer, ping me and I will delete mine.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I'm good, it was almost simultaneous posting after all. In fact tempted to remove my comments and leave it there, since my argument that the formula doesn't give the desired probability makes little sense in hindsight ...

Comment: This expression (edited just a few minutes ago) looks right.  Its value is roughly $\exp\left(-\frac{n^2}{2m}\right)$.  Since $2m = 2(52!) \approx 1.6 \times 10^{68}$ and $n^2 = 10^{28}$, this is essentially $1-\frac{n^2}{2m}$ to a very good approximation.

Comment: Changing the question (here by multiplying by $n!$) invalidates the answers that have already been posted.  You have not changed the claim that this is the chance of two shuffles matching, but give no justification.

Comment: Changing the question after have received answer is not very fair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x = \frac{\binom mn}{m^n}=\frac{\Gamma (m+1)}{m^n\,\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (m+1-n)}$$
Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation for large $m$ since $52! \sim 8\times 10^{67}$
$$\log(x)=-\log (n!)-\frac{(n-1) n}{2 m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)\implies x \sim \frac 1{n!}$$

**Edit**  *(after the edit of the question)*

$$x = \frac{n!\,\binom mn}{m^n}=\frac1{m^{n}}\frac{ \Gamma (m+1)}{\Gamma (m-n+1)}$$ Do the same as above to obtain

$$\log(x)=-\frac{(n-1) n}{2 m}-\frac{(n-1) n (2 n-1)}{12
   m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)\tag 1$$
$$x=e^{\log(x)}=1-\frac{(n-1) n}{2 m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$ and this $n$ is very large, then
$$x \sim 1-\frac {n^2}{2m}$$ which was already given by @Brian Tung
in comments.

Using your numbers
$\log(x) \sim -6.199000\times 10^{-41}$ while $(1)$ gives the **same** number if you accept an absolute difference of $1.588\times 10^{-149}$.

Comment: Note that OP has changed the expression by a factor of $n!$.

Comment: @BrianTung. Thank you for mentioning it. Cheers :-)

Comment: you mean for large m?

Comment: @gdcpb. I first made it for large $m$. Now, we need to consider that $n$ is large too even if $n \ll m$

Answer (score 3):

${m \choose n}=\frac {m(m-1)(m-2)...(m-n+1)}{n!}\lt \frac {m^n}{n!}$ so your fraction is less than $\frac 1{n!}$.  For $n \approx 10^{14}$ this is very small.  This is not the probability that two decks out of $10^{14}$ match.  See the [generalized birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Arbitrary_number_of_days) for that.  Very roughly, you will have a reasonable chance of a match when you have a number of samples that is the square root of the size of the sample space.  With $52! \approx 10^{68}$ you need about $10^{34}$ samples to have a reasonable chance of a match.  Wikipedia does a better job with the constants.

Comment: could you provide edit for the actual formula? using stirling's approximation

Comment: Note that OP has changed the expression by a factor of $n!$.